# How to loop through the extjs grid object to get its elements and values

Tags: extjs, grid

I have created a grid and want to access it when I click on save button in a page.
How can I loop the grid object to get its elements and its values?

Comment: Please look in here http://edspencer.net/2009/07/ext-js-iterator-functions.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to get a particular field from each record:

```
var data = [];
store.each(function(rec){
    data.push(rec.get('field'));
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the answer to my question:

```
for (var i = 0; i < yourGrid.getStore().data.length; i++) { 
    var element = Ext.get(yourGrid.getView().getRow(i));
    var record = yourGrid.getStore().getAt(i);
    alert(record.data.ID);
}
```

Comment: That's a poor way to do it. See below.

Answer (score 4):

How do you get the rows from the grid?

```
var rows = grid.getStore().getRange();
```

rows will be an Array of [Record](http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/output/Ext.data.Record.html) objects.

Comment: can i get example  of "Record objects" ?

Comment: A record is the data behind a row in the grid.

Answer (score 4):

In order to get DOM of the row you can use following code :

```
yourGrid.getNode(yourGrid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex))
```

or you can use getNode directly but incase of any headerbar it may not work as supposed to.

```
yourGrid.getNode(rowIndex)
```

This will give you the table row.